How to obtain a sketchy/painty/roughjs/semiotic look with ggplot2
I know that with the gradient features introduced in version 4.1 of R, more is possible with respect to graphics. As such, how can I (or is it even possible to) obtain a sketchy and/or painty look as in the following, which is from Semiotic (https://web.archive.org/web/20211019161924/https://semiotic.nteract.io/guides/sketchy-painty-patterns). Basically, I want to obtain a hand-drawn and/or a hand-painted look when I shade in my graphs and choropleth maps (possibly with some degree of randomness in how it is made).

An example with alternating colors from https://medium.com/data-visualization-society/you-can-design-a-good-chart-with-r-5d00ed7dd18e:

Two other examples are taken from sketchy from d3.js (https://github.com/sebastian-meier/d3.sketchy):


And more examples from https://roughjs.com/:



I am very aware of ggrough, but, at least in the past, it required extra work to get it working and didn't work all of the time. See:
Unable to replicate this ggplot2 plot
and
How to shade shapes

https://github.com/schochastics/roughsf for choropleth maps? (Following suggestions from https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/ about what packages are more current ...)

the xkcd package provides some options to make plots look more hand-drawn, but I don't think it has sketchy style fills
